# script for making combinations of gameobjects in c# Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, combinations, gameobject

i want make a script that will generate a collection of gameobjects like this:
(given gameobjects) a, b, c
result: a, b, c, ab, ac, bc, abc
i found a script

```
static IEnumerable<string> Combinations(List<string> characters, int length)
{
for (int i = 0; i < characters.Count; i++)
{
    // only want 1 character, just return this one
    if (length == 1)
        yield return characters[i];

    // want more than one character, return this one plus all combinations one shorter
    // only use characters after the current one for the rest of the combinations
    else
        foreach (string next in Combinations(characters.GetRange(i + 1, characters.Count - (i + 1)), length - 1))
            yield return characters[i] + next;
}
}
```

but its only for strings so if i missed any solution which can work here i would be grateful.

Comment: Call it with `gameObjects.Select(o => o.Name)` to build the permutations of names, then look up the objects by name again?

Comment: Note that combinations and permutations are ***very*** different concepts